# If we have an embedding $f:X \rightarrow A$, where $A \subset Y$, do we have to show $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, definition

If we have an embedding $f:X \rightarrow A$, where $A \subset Y$, do we have to show $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

I'm looking at a proof where they only show that $f$ is continuous and 1-1.  Then I looked at the Wikipedia article on embeddings,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding

"In general topology, an embedding is a one-to-one function (i.e., an injection) that is a homeomorphism onto its image.[1] More explicitly, an injective continuous map f : X → Y between topological spaces X and Y is a topological embedding if f yields a homeomorphism between X and f(X) (where f(X) carries the subspace topology inherited from Y). Intuitively then, the embedding f : X → Y lets us treat X as a subspace of Y. Every embedding is injective and continuous. Every map that is injective, continuous and either open or closed is an embedding; however there are also embeddings which are neither open nor closed. The latter happens if the image f(X) is neither an open set nor a closed set in Y."

I'm confused. Is there a difference, in topology, between an embedding and a topological embedding?  Are there some cases where I don't have to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

EDIT: $X,Y$ are compact metric spaces.

Comment: In the proof at which you’re looking, what else is known about $X$? If, for instance, $X$ is compact, it’s enough to show that $f$ is continuous and $1$-$1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: ... and $Y$ or $A$ are Hausdorff, ...

Comment: Yes, $X,Y$ are compact.  I was thinking about that,...what does that do?

Comment: Every continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism (should be in any standard intro to topology course/textbook). [here's a proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism)

Comment: @DanielRust: You are right, I found it. I didn't expect this. Thanks.

Comment: "Embedding" may be used in more restrictive ways in a particular context, e.g., an isometric embedding. But if all you have are topological spaces, or all you're considering is topology, then "embedding" is synonymous with "topological embedding".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If, as in this case, $X$ is compact and $A$ is Hausdorff, it suffices to show that $f:X\to A$ is a continuous bijection. To see this, let $F$ be a closed set in $X$. Then $F$ is compact, and $f$ is continuous, so $f[F]$ is compact in $A$ and therefore closed in $A$, since compact sets in a Hausdorff space are closed. Thus, $f$ is a closed map. Now let $U$ be any open set in $X$; then $X\setminus U$ is closed, and $f[U]=A\setminus f[X\setminus U]$ is open, since $f$ is a bijection, and $f^{-1}$ is therefore continuous.

Comment: Why do you conclude from this that $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

Comment: Because $f$ is an open map and $(f^{-1})^{-1} = f$.